# Finding Strings in a NSMutableArray Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Is it possible to find the index of a NSMutableArray based on the begging of a string. For instance if I had the NSMutableArray `["Joe","Jim","Jason"]` and I wanted to find the index where the beginning of the string contains `"Jo"` so that it would return index `0` for `"Joe"`. Basically just trying to find an index based on part of a string rather than the whole string itself.

Comment: Have you tried anything? And why are you using `NSMutableArray` in Swift instead of a native Swift array?

Comment: @rmaddy I have tried using `.index(of:)` and I'm using a `NSMutableArray` because it's a variable in my objective-c class where data is being added to the array.

Comment: Objective-C? But the question only talks about Swift. Which is it?

Comment: @rmaddy It's swift, my swift file is where I'm trying to find a particular string in the array but I only used a `NSMutableArray` because of the way my Objective-C file works that is linked to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` conforms to `Collection`, and as such, it inherits the default method `index(where:)`, which does exactly what you're looking for:

```
import Foundation

let names = ["Joe","Jim","Jason"]
let desiredPrefix = "Jo"

if let index = names.index(where: { $0.hasPrefix(desiredPrefix) }) {
    print("The first name starting with \(desiredPrefix) was found at \(index)") 
}
else {
    print("No names were found that start with \(desiredPrefix)")
}
```

If you do this often, you can clean up your code by putting it in a function that extends `Collection`s of `String`s:

```
import Foundation

extension Collection where Iterator.Element == String {
    func first(withPrefix prefix: String) -> Self.Index? {
        return self.index(where: { $0.hasPrefix(prefix)})
    }
}

let names = ["Joe","Jim","Jason"]
let desiredPrefix = "Jo"

if let index = names.first(withPrefix: desiredPrefix) {
    print("The first name starting with \(desiredPrefix) was found at \(index)") 
}
else {
    print("No names were found that start with \(desiredPrefix)")
}
```

Comment: When I tried that it came up with the error `Argument labels '(where:)' do not match any available overloads`

Comment: @SpartanEngr1297 Works fine in this [Swift 3.1 sandbox](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58e29dd281da4259378b9940). What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Same version, I'm invoking it on the variable of my objective-c class as such `let index = myfirstconnection.information.index(where: {$0.hasPrefix("Jobs")})` where `myfirstconnection` is the class instance and `information` is the `NSMutableArray`

Comment: @SpartanEngr1297 - give this a try (although not a finished solution - just to get you on your way): `if let index = ((myfirstconnection.information) as! [String]).index(where: { $0.hasPrefix(pref) }) {`

Comment: @SpartanEngr1297 Oh my bad, I thought I had made my array an `NSMutableArray`